# Extracting values from an array object

Tags: powershell

How do i extract the first value from `times` and `data` from an array object and continue with the rest until i am done with all values?

```
PS S:\Files\Scripts> $memory

times                                                           data
-----                                                           ----
{1548401348221, 1548401358224, 1548401368227, 1548401378227...} {50.47999954223633, 50.47999954223633, 50.47999954223633, 50.47999954223633...}
```

Comment: How did you acquire `$memory`? May be easier to get in a step earlier possibly with `ConvertFrom-Json` What does `$memory.gettype()` return?

Answer (score 1):

One a bit clumsy way:

```
$times = $memory.times.trim('{}') -split ', '
$data  = $memory.data.trim('{}') -split ', '

$newMemory = for ($i=0;$i -lt $times.count;$i++){
    [PSCUstomObject]@{
         times = $times[$i]
         data  = $data[$i]
    }
}

$newMemory

times         data
-----         ----
1548401348221 50.47999954223633
1548401358224 50.47999954223633
1548401368227 50.47999954223633
1548401378227 50.47999954223633
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and Appreciate it.  I ran into below error when i tried to trim it.   Method invocation failed because [System.Int64] does not contain a method named 'trim'.   $Memory appears to be a system object and  i might have to convert it

Comment: Please EDIT your question to contain the information I asked for in above comment. Eventually just use `$times = $memory.times` etc.

Comment: Sorry, i just noticed your question.  that did the trick. thanks again

Comment: To be of any use for followup readers you should elaborate how you solved the problem - otherwise better delete the question.